# eBay API limit findItemsByProduct to Regional Site

Tags: ebay-api

Im trying to use the Ebay API in order to find items by ISBN or UPC.
Using the [findItemsByProduct API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html)

Using the following URL (Replacing MY_APP_ID with a real one), I can get a list of items that match the UPC of Inception `883929106646`

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=MY_APP_ID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&productId.@type=UPC&productId=883929106646&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3

However, I want to limit this to `Ebay UK` items only.

The documentation says that you should pass `GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB` in the URL but then I get the following error (with no other changes to the URL):

```
<findItemsByProductResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<ack>Failure</ack>
<errorMessage>
<error>
<errorId>41</errorId>
<domain>Marketplace</domain>
<severity>Error</severity>
<category>Request</category>
<message>Invalid product ID value.</message>
<subdomain>Search</subdomain>
<parameter>883929106646</parameter>
</error>
</errorMessage>
<version>1.13.0</version>
<timestamp>2016-02-12T10:07:44.800Z</timestamp>
</findItemsByProductResponse>
```

How can I limit this product search to Ebay UK?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried changing the url to http://svcs.ebay.co.uk?

Comment: try: `header('X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-GB');`

Comment: @mkaatman - changing the URL doesnt seem to make a difference. EBAY-DE causes same issue. Will try the header

Comment: @mkaatman setting the header causes the same issue as above. Removing the header again makes the request work but doesnt limit to EBAY Uk

Comment: All product ids are returning that same error as well?

Comment: @mkaatman seems to work with other IDs? Weird. If you want the bounty - add an answer

Comment: I'll take it. I don't feel like I've solved your problem though! My best guess is that particular sku doesn't work in the UK store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular SKU you're looking for isn't available in the UK store.